# Differentiablity of distance function.

Tags: real-analysis

Take the closed interval $[0,1]$ and open interval $(1/3,2/3).$Let $K=[0,1] \(1/3,2/3).$ For $x\in[0,1]$ define $f(x)=d(x,K)$ where $d(x,K)=$inf$\{$ |x-y|:y $\in$ K}. Then

$1. f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at all points of $(0,1)$

$2. f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is not differentiable at $1/3$ and $2/3.$

$3. f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is not differentiable at $1/2.$

$4. f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is not continuoius.

Since distance function is continuous so $4$th option is not correct. Again $f$ is not differentiable at $1/3$ and $2/3$ so 1st option is wrong and second one is correct. But my confusion is about $3$rd option. According to me $f$ is not differentable at $1/2$ as it seems to be like $|x-1/2|$ function at $1/2$. Please suggest me about differentiablity of $f$ at $1/2.$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of $f$ on the interval (1/3,2/3)? If you can answer this the truth/falsity of option 3 should be clear.

Comment: if possible please give some answer

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question. To show non differentiability, show that limits of the derivatives as $x \rightarrow 1/2$ from above and below and different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is:

- $f(x)= 0$ for $x\in [0,1/3]$ as well as for $x\in [2/3,1]$.
- $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}$ for $x\in (1/3,1/2]$
- $f(x)=\frac{2}{3}-x$ for $x\in [1/2,2/3)$.
  It is easy to see that graph of $f(x)$ has sharp corners at the points $x=1/3, 1/2$ and $2/3$.

Comment: yes thanks a lot....